# Modify current object element in javascript in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to implement a local cart in an e-commerce application, so i have some products like and each product is a object which looks like:

```
    [
        { prodId: 1, count: 1 },
        { prodId: 2, count: 1 },
        { prodId: 3, count: 1 },
        and so onn...
    ]
```

Now here, if a user adds a product for the very first time it gets added perfectly in local storage and getting rendered perfectly on the cart screen, all I'm doing is storing that object in an json string in local storage.

Also if a user adds a product with different productId, it too works well.

But if user adds same product again, which is already present in cart, I want to just increase the count of that productId.

```
    async btnPressed() {
        const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem("obj");
        let val = JSON.parse(item);
        if (val === null) { //Adding a product for first time
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem("obj");
            let newVal = [];
            let count = { counter: 1 };
            let newObj = Object.assign(count, this.props.obj);
            newVal.push(newObj);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("obj", 
                JSON.stringify(newVal));

            ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                "Product added to cart!",
                ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                ToastAndroid.CENTER
            );
         } else {


    //Product is already present, increasing count here
               val.some(element => {
                   if (element.ProductID === this.props.obj.ProductID) {
                       AsyncStorage.removeItem("obj").then(() => console.warn("in val some"));
                       val.pop(element);
                       console.warn(val);
                       element.counter = element.counter + 1;
                       val.push(element);
                       console.warn(val);
                       AsyncStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(val)).then(() => console.warn("Done"));
                       ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                           "Product added to cart!",
                           ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                           ToastAndroid.CENTER
                       );
                       return true;
                   } 
               }); 

    // Adding a new product with different productID

    const checkObj = await AsyncStorage.getItem('obj');
    let fetchedObj = JSON.parse(checkObj);
    if(fetchedObj === null) {}
        let count = { counter: 1 };
        let newObj = Object.assign(count, this.props.obj);
        console.warn(val);
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("obj");
        val.push(newObj);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(val))
        ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
            "Product added to cart!",
            ToastAndroid.SHORT,
            ToastAndroid.CENTER
        );
     }
  }
```

Is my logic proper or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Some is just to check if there's at least one element that meets the evaluation inside your function. Since these are functions that keep the array immutable, that's why you're not seeing your changes.

Just get the found object from the find, and based on it run your logic:

```
let foundElement = val.find(element => element.ProductID === this.props.obj.ProductID );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```js
class Cart {
  // Load the cart state
  async load() {
    this.cartContent = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart'));
  }

  // Save the cart state
  async saveCart() {
    return AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', this.cartContent);
  }

  // Add a product into the cart
  async addProduct(productName) {
    // If the cart is empty add the new item
    if (this.cartContent === null) {
      this.cartContent = [{
        name: productName,
        quantity: 1,
      }];

      return this.saveCart();
    }

    // If the cart is not empty
    // Look if the product already exist
    const product = this.cartContent.find(x => x.name === productName);

    if (product) {
      product.quantity += 1;
    } else {
      this.cartContent.push({
        name: productName,
        quantity: 1,
      });
    }

    return this.saveCart();
  }

  // Remove a product from the cart
  async removeProduct(productName) {
    // You understood what's up now
  }
}

async addProductBtnPressed() {
  const cart = new Cart();

  // Load my cart
  await cart.load();

  // Add a new product
  cart.addProduct('whatever');
}
```